# "Водичку пьют и хлеб жуют, а супчик насыпают"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в выражении "Водичку пьют и хлеб жуют, а супчик насыпают"?

Comment: Чтобы не создавать похожий **отдельный** вопрос, попробую написать здесь. Одни говорят "супчик (или борщ) насыпают", а другие "супчик наливают". Оба варианта правильные? Или есть разница?

Answer (score 1):

Тире здесь не является обязательным, но поставить его можно для выразительности, чтобы подчеркнуть действие.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо загромождать предложение лишними знаками. Обычное предложение с однородными членами.

Answer (score 0):

Тире ставить не стоит, так как оно будет излишним.
Отвечаю на вопрос, почему люди говорят "супчик насыпают". Так говорят либо шутники, желающие придать немного абсурдности своей речи, либо неграмотные люди. Так как суп - жидкость, правильно его наливать.